# How to access DbContext in/from Program class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have setup an ASP.NET Core project, and configured the `DbContext` in Startup.cs like -

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));
}
```

I can access the `DbContext` object in controller classes with dependency injection. But I need a reference of the `DbContext` in the Program class (in Program.cs file).

I tried the following approach, but it indicates syntax error -

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new DBContext())    // getting syntax error here
        {
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }


    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseUrls("http://localhost:4000");
            });
}
```

So, how to get access to the `DbContext` object in the Program class?

Comment: I need to find a way to get dbcontext in program.cs like we access the same in any other controller..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have registered and configured your database context using dependency injection, you cannot just create a context using `new` since you would be skipping the configuration that way.

Instead, you will need to retrieve the database context from the dependency injection service provider, which is available from the `Host` that is being built in your `Program`.

Since the database context has a scoped lifetime by default, you will need to create a scope first, retrieve the database context within that scope, and finally dispose the scope again when you are done.

This should look like this:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DBContext>();
        db.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    host.Run();
}
```